# How to get current theme name from linux desktop environment using Qt C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, themes, desktop-application

I am going to develop an app using Qt, and I want to use the icons in **/usr/share/icons** directory, however, I don't know how to make the icons change automatically when the desktop evironment theme changed.

I use QIcon and declaring the icon path by absolute path, for example, I want to use **Numix-Circle** icon theme, so I did this:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton ;
QIcon icon ( '/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48/apps/gnome-do.svg' ) ;
button -> setText ( "" ) ;
button -> setIcon ( icon );
```

But the icon will not change with the DE theme change, furthermore , if the user doesn't install the theme, the icon in app will not show.

Is there any way to get the icons from desktop environment?or the other way to make the icons in app responsive?

Comment: [`QIcon::fromTheme()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme)?

Comment: I found that the theme name return from  `QIcon::themeName()` is **adwaita** but I am using **numix** now. I will try fromTheme function again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QIcon::fromTheme("gnome-do")` will return a QIcon from the current theme. In KDE, if you change the icon theme, the icons should also update to match the new theme.

Comment: Perhaps... But this doesn't work in other DEs (like Xfce). So, there must be a way for a Qt-based non-KDE application to get notified when icon theme changes.

Comment: That's up to the internal icon engine to implement. Does the icon change in a KDE app on Xfce when the icon theme is changed?